# Using OpenID Connect ID token for application-to-application authentication/authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

(Apologies in advance for possible misuse of the word authentication/authorization)

I am building up several web applications that talks to each other with an identity provider that looks like this.

```
         A -----> idP
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
    \/_     _\/  
    B         C
```

Where application A will make requests to B and C to push and pull data, and it has to do so in the context of the user that's using application A.  Given that I am using OAuth2 on the idP, my first thought is using the bearer token issued by the identity provider, and pass that around to each application as a way to "login" from application A to B/C.

Problem with that approach is that B/C doesn't know who that bearer token belongs to.  In order to make this work, I would have to create an end point on the idP to get user information that B/C can use to figure out the user.  While this could work, I wanted to see if there was something more standard out there I can use.  That's when I found OpenID Connect.

From what I can see, OpenID Connect basically replaces the bearer token with a JWT, and signs it with a private key to prevent tampering.  Given that, here's the flow I am thinking of:

- User authenticates against web application A, application A receives ID token from idP, create a logged in session for the user and store the ID token as part of the session
- Application A needs to retrieve data from application B in the context of user, so it sends the ID token to application B as part of the request
- Application B gets the ID token from the header, gets the public key from the idP, and validates the signature.
- If signature is validated, then the rest of the JWT is validated (expiry, issuer, issued time stamp, audience)
- If all the checks are valid, then the data is returned from B to A

I have a couple of question about using OpenID Connect in this manner:

- In OpenID Connect, the JWT's audience field can contain multiple client IDs, but from what I understand, the idP is suppose to only return the client requesting for the token.  So how does the idP know what other client ID to put into the audience field?
- How to best handle logout?  Since each application maintains its own session, my thinking is that logout should invalidate the individual sessions on application A/B/C, then the session on idP to completely logout.  Would that be best handled with an AJAX request to each application?

Answer (score 3):

Although this isn't answering directly your questions, let me add comments to it as I am currently asking myself similar questions. This is also based on my humble understanding.

Regarding the audience (`aud` claim) of an *ID Token*, at the time of initial registration, your client registration could include what other applications (registered as OAuth clients too) your client would like to access. This could then be used to always include such an audience list when an ID Token is issued for your client. Check also the `azp` (authorized party) claim that should contain your client id. That's said, I haven't seen examples of tools managing this at registration time.

About your comment of the ID Token replacing the bearer token (i.e. Access Token), I have been looking at a standard way (e.g. specific Authorization header) to pass an ID Token when calling another application, but I didn't find any. I am not sure if a standard Authorization Bearer should be used or if there is another standard way of passing an ID Token.

Note also that, as far as I saw, ID Tokens have limitations to be used beyond being a short-live token, as:

- they cannot be refreshed when they expire (even refreshing the linked Access Token isn't returning a refreshed ID Token)
- they cannot be revoked (even if the linked Access Token could be), e.g. to manage a logout

They seem to more intended to be used to initiate a session (in a way similar to SAML assertions), like what you described, but you would rather copy ID Token claims and additional information retrieved from the UserInfo endpoint into your session information as your session may last longer than the duration of the ID Token.

That being said, if we want to use an ID token as some evidence of the user authentication, this wouldn't work after the token is expired, so I am not sure that trying to keep and use it during a whole session is a good idea.
If this is used as part of a short chain of calls or to create a new session with downstream applications (including initiating a JWT grant type OAuth flow with the ID token as an evidence of user identity), this may be what this is targeted at.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had similar thoughts, and I kind of abandoned the idea and left it alone.  After about a year I came back to it, and I had the idea to work around this issue by going through an API manager instead.  Basically I won't try to validate another application's token, but have the API manager validate it instead, and then generate another token for the intended SP.